# Visual Studio Custom Window for VSIX using WPF Can't find theme in other project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-extensions

I developed a stand alone WPF project with the ShinyBlue.xaml theme which works fine.  Now I want to create a VSIX project to include some user controls from that project right in Visual Studio.

[image]

**Problem**

The VSIX project XAML shows the error above.  Where poc:UCMAIN is a user control in the first project that works perfect!

**Possible Solutions**

1. Get rid of my styling in first project that required a static
   resource due to the stlye based on property.  I don't want that
   because I won't get the color.  Not a good solution.
2. Copy the theme into the VSIX project and try to get is found there.  Problem with that is there is not app.config file in VSIX projects.  I can add a merged dictionary to the VSIX project main window but.... it still doen't locate the BlueButton Resource.

**Question**

Why does VSIX project show the error above?  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
VSIX custom windows doesn't appear to reach into the other included Project's XAML resource directories. Even when the merged dictionary points to the theme.

I was using global styling with the targetType parameter and the basedOn parameter specifying a key I placed into the theme to "grab" that color for those buttons.

1. I removed the key value
2. I moved command parameter bindings from the resources styling area to be contained in each button.
3. Themes may be used but the Main.XAML control must merge the theme dictionary instead of the app.config file which is not present in VSIX Tool Window solutions.